# "The link you followed has expired." message when activating or deactivating plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am getting an error showing in Wordpress when trying to activate or deactivate a plugin.

It results in this error message: "The link you followed has expired."

Have done some research on the internets, the consensus is to add the following to the htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 1000
```

I have done this similarly in the php.ini file.

Don't believe these settings are the answer as when I click "activate" it doesn't really take much time to load it will go straight to the page.

Have also looked at the caching program WP-Rocket, no solution there either.

Updated to include the server settings here:

[image: Server settings]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this happens for all plugins or a specific plugin ?

Comment: Thanks @amilaishere yes this is for all plugins.

Answer (score 1):

can you also add the following value in .htaccess

```
php upload_max_size = 64M
```

---

### Method  2

Have you tried editing the php.ini file with the following, if you do have access ?

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_size = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 1000
```

if both of them do not work,we will need more information about your envirnment- wordpress,php version ? are you on local or on a staging environment?

Comment: In addition, if you are hosting online, you can upload a file to your webserver called phpinfo.php and inside add the following code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then view that file in your browser. That will show you your limits serverside.

Comment: Hey @christie, thanks for the post here, however adding `php upload_max_size = 64M` to the `.htaccess` file results in an `internal server error`. Also have updated the php.ini file that PHP is using with no success either. This is a production server. Apache/2.4.43 (Ubuntu) and 7.4.7 (Supports 64bit values).

Comment: Hi can you try the debugging(https://wordpress.org/support/article/common-wordpress-errors/#the-white-screen-of-death) suggested by wordpress. please debug in another instance like your local or staging. please can you share if this helps.?